# What does slipped over sausage mean?

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

I was watching "[Dad's army](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaxkLVtRY1U)" trailer/teaser and at [0:58](https://youtu.be/HaxkLVtRY1U?t=58) one of the actresses says something like

> I saw that you just slipped over sausage(s)

- What actually this means? Is it like other "slipped over" idioms or
  not?
- Could it be also an idiom that is translated from another language?
  (for instance German)

Comment: The middle word is “her”, not “over”, pronounced in a British way without the “H” sound. “I saw that, you just slipped ‘er a sausage”. The sausage in this case is literal: you can see the man in the hat hand her a paper-wrapped cylindrical package: a sausage in a wrap. The pseudo-risqué element is that “to slip [a woman] your sausage” is a metaphorical way to say you’ve had sex with her (sausage = penis, slip in = penetrate). But in this case it’s an actual sausage. Maybe he’s a butcher. Anyway, no mystery here.

Comment: Aha! Thanks, mate this makes sense,

Comment: @DanBron The butcher has literally just passed the woman in question some sausage(s) but given the context it's probably intended as a double entendre.

Comment: @KillingTime Thanks, I noticed that on my second watching and have already updated my comment.

Comment: @DanBron Lance Corporal Jones **is** a butcher in his civilian life. One of his catch-phrases in the famous TV series (the movie was a spin-off with a different cast) was "**They don't like it up 'em!**"

Comment: @DanBron Bloody nora I was going to answer that question but then I saw your comment. :((( And there's no way I can add anything extra… Rations! Sausages, meat, dairy products, etc. were heavily rationed in Great Britain during WWII. So slipping someone a piece of meat was naughty... in both senses of the word.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That’s a useful addition, I was wondering why it would be (outside of the double entendre) such a scandal, or at least noteworthy, to hand a lady a sausage. Why not make an answer of my comment and that observation? I’ll upvote you.

Comment: @DanBron  Someone else. I relinquish *i diritti d'autore* (author's rights).

Comment: Would one of you kindly please write an answer? There is useful information here that should not be lost in comments.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a mishearing of the words spoken in the film clip.